# not saving all option values for multiselect attribute in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have custom multiselect product attribute which contains more than 700 values. when I select all values and save product it saves some values around 60 but not saving all option values.

I have already increase limitation of max_input_vars 10000 in on Linux server.

Is there any solution to save all values?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: yes, change attribute value field type from varchar to text in catalog_product_entity_varchar table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change attribute value field type from varchar to text in catalog_product_entity_varchar table.

Comment: how to save values programmatically?